# Item in ItemsControl is not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have list of pictures in an ItemsControl block as shown below

```
<ItemsControl Name="icAvatars">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding LdVis}" Text="Loading... "/>
                        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ErrVis}" Text="Error while loading the image."/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImgSrc}" Visibility="{Binding ImgVis}"/>
                    </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Any time when a new picture should be added to the list, an object is instantiated from the class Avatar and added to the list.

```
public class Avatar
{
    public BitmapImage ImgSrc { get; set; }
    public Visibility LdVis { get; set; }
    public Visibility ImgVis { get; set; }
    public Visibility ErrVis { get; set; }
}

Avatar avatar = new Avatar();
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
bitmap.ImageOpened += (s, e) => avatar.ShowImage();
avatar.ImgSrc = bitmap;
icAvatars.Items.Add(avatar);
```

The problem is that when the image is loaded and I try to change its visibility property (by using avatar.ImgVis), seems the change on avatar object is not propagated to the actual image. Why this happens?

Comment: Try using `Mode=TwoWay` in your xaml code in the element.

Comment: I tried that. Nothing changed.

Comment: where are you assigning values to your visibility property..?? Ldvis and ErrVis

Comment: try to call RaisePropertyChanged Event ....

Comment: I do it in the event handler of ImageOpened. You can see the edited code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Avatar` class should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and each time `ImgVis` property is changed `PropertyChanged` event should be raised. Same thing should apply to all data bound properties that can can change at runtime.

```
public class Avatar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private Visibility _imgVis;

    public Visibility ImgVis 
    { 
       get{ return _imgVis; }
       set
       { 
          if (value == _imgVis) return;
          _imgVis = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("ImgVis");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: did at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this is because you have not implement the inotifypropertychange on you avatar class so for doinng that just do like this..
public class Assignment  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{




    private Visibility _ImgVis ;
    public Visibility ImgVis 
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImgVis ;
        }
        set
        {
            _ImgVis  = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("ImgVis ");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

it will always update whatever changes you will made to your avatar propeties ..if you want to the changes on avatar on add and del...either make it a observable collection

Comment: Sorry that I can just choose a single answer as correct. Anyway, thanks so much :)